# Get custom property types using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Suppose I have a class (something like this):

```
public class User
{
   public Guid Id { get; set;}
   public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public UserGroup Group { get; set; } 
}
```

Is there a way get all property types that are not part of the .NET Framework.
So in this case I want to get only `UserGroup` ? Is that possible ?

The best thing I can come up with is something like:

`IEnumerable<Type> types = typeof(User).GetProperties().Where(p => !p.PropertyType.Namespace.StartsWith("System.")).Select(t => t.PropertyType);`

But this looks like a hack-job. Sorry if dup, couldn't find anything like that, and sorry for the formatting, did my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have is probably reliable enough for what you want. However, from a flexibility/readability point of view maybe it would be better to define your own attribute type which you could apply at property level i.e.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [CustomProperty]
    public UserGroup Group { get; set; }
}
```

You could then use reflection to query all the properties which have this attribute. This would give you the ability to include/exclude *any* properties.

---

> Sorry I forgot to mention that I can't modify the domain entities. (can't add an attribute).

You can use the [MetadataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) to add attributes to a base class e.g.

```
class UserMetadata
{
    ...
    [CustomProperty]
    public UserGroup Group { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata)]
public class DomainUser : User
{
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I can't modify the domain entities. (can't add an attribute). I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Thank you, this is an approach I haven't thought of. I'll give it a shot (looks cleaner).

Comment: Nice solution. But does it always work? What if the User-class was sealed?

Comment: @MartinMulder if the `User` class was `sealed` then no the above wouldn't work as you couldn't derive from `User`. However, you could create a wrapper class which took in a `User` and exposed the properties, it's not great but it would do the job.

Comment: True... it would not be a `great` job. I myself would rely on logic of the computer: let the computer do the work :)

Comment: Well in these particular scenarios, where your hands are tied, there's not much else you can do...

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is always some kind of hacking, so yes, it FEELS like a hackjob.

But analyzing the entity, the class, will have to be done with reflection. So you are doing it the correct way.

One pitfall. You yourself are able to create your own types inside a namespace "System". That would mess up your search. You also could also analyze then Assembly of the property type, but then you have to know of all .NET assemblies, which is a big list.

Comment: Although your technically correct, you should never really be adding your own custom types to the `System` namespace - it violates the [namespace guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/893ke618(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is fine, you could do something like this however and make use of the `Except` method.

```
public static Type[] GetNonSystemTypes<T>()
{
  var systemTypes = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(t => t.PropertyType).Where(t => t.Namespace == "System");
  return typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(t => t.PropertyType).Except(systemTypes).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Not really seeing why introducing the `Except` helps here? All it does is make the code longer.

Comment: @James just because code is longer, doesn't mean it is any worse - the majority of time infact, it is better. Just presenting an alternative way of doing it?

Comment: Longer code is better if it actually helps in some way - this doesn't. This is like saying instead of writing `var i = 0` you can do `int i; i = 0;`. Why do something in 2 lines when it can be done in one, especially when it doesn't *add* anything to the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works.  I would just throw in that you could also try to check the Assembly the type was defined in, and for example check if it was loaded from the global assembly cache.

```
bool wasLoadedFromAssemblyCache = typeof(T).Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache;
```

Comment: Nice way of thinking, but, what if Dimitar also puts his DLL's in the GAC?

Comment: @MartinMulder: of course.  I meant the example more as an idea starter for checking the Assembly's properties in general, not necessarily the GAC property.  For example, you could check the name of the assembly, if the custom types are in the same assembly.